# Relation between $_SESSION and $_REQUEST

Tags: php, session, request

Here's my case :

I'm using SugarCRM's API, and to make a call, I had to patch some functions to make things work. In one of the function, I had to rewrite this code :

```
$credentials = array('user_name'=>"xxxxxxx", 'password'=>md5("xxxxx"));
    if (SugarWebServiceImpl::login($credentials, null, null)) {
    global $current_user;
    require_once('modules/Users/User.php');
    $current_user = new User();
    $current_user->retrieve($_SESSION['user_id']);
    $this->login_success();
    return true;
}
```

My problem is that on the same call, my variable `$_REQUEST` becomes empty. My question is simple then :

is there any relation between the `$_SESSION` variable and the `$_REQUEST` variable. Does the `$_REQUEST` empties herself when a new `$_SESSION` is set ?

Comment: At what point is it not empty? At what point does it become empty? Hard to help when your code doesn't say `$_REQUEST` even once. There's no relationship between the two, `$_REQUEST` lasts only for the current request and `$_SESSION` last for as long as your sessions are configured

Comment: @JuanMendes "Hard to help when your code doesn't say $_REQUEST even once." - "There's no relationship between the two" -> That's just what I was trying to know.

Comment: So there's no actual problem to solve? If it's just a theoretical question, that's not a good fit for SO. SO is for problems you are trying to solve. For general questions about programmming go to http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ State what the actual problem is, there is no indication anywhere in documentation that would indicate `$_REQUEST` and `$_SESSION` are related

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, There is not.
According to [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php)

`$_REQUEST` is
`An associative array that by default contains the contents of $_GET, $_POST and $_COOKIE.`

However that just answers your question but doesn't solve the problem. If that issue happens here

`$current_user->retrieve($_SESSION['user_id']);`

then it would help to be able to see that retrieve method

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, indeed it doesn't solve my problem here. It seems that the `$_REQUEST` is empty even before creating my new session.

Answer (score 1):

No, `$_SESSION` and `$_REQUEST` have no relation whatsoever.

Answer (score 1):

`$_SESSION` and `$_REQUEST` are unrelated.

`$_SESSION` - variables stored in the session scope (per user), e.g. available until `PHPSESSID` cookie is set by `session_start()` and remains set in the user browser.

`$_REQUEST` - parameters provider for the current request, either query parameters (also accessible via `$_GET`, post/form fields (also accessible via `$_POST` or cookies (also accessible via `$_COOKIES`).